# Split tar.gz files using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, gzip, file-read

I am importing data feed into mywebsite.My datafeed files are came from tar.gz format. The file size is is very large upto 10 gb. i need to split tar.gz file and then upload to database.  How can i split tar.gz single file to multiple file. Please Guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create several parts like this:

```
$fileName = 'something_big.tar.gz';
$fileSize = filesize($fileName);
$parts = 10;
$partSize = ceil($fileSize / 10);

$f_in = fopen($fileName, 'rb');
for ($i = 0; $i < $parts; ++$i) {
    $f_out = fopen("$fileName.$i", 'wb');
    stream_copy_to_stream($f_in, $f_out, $partSize);
    fclose($f_out);
}
fclose($f_in);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. i have one small doubt my split files are goes to another folder. how can i do this. please guide

Comment: @user2189641 Just change the filename when you create the files.

Comment: Hi @jack. split zip file running very good but the zip files are not extract with me. please tell me what's wrong

Comment: @user well, you need to recombine the files later before the file works again.

Comment: now how i can create 1 file from this parts ?

Comment: @VishalRibdiya in the same way, but reversing the input / output